# What language(s) was the "The Mother of All Demos" written in?

Tags: demo

For the "*[The Mother of All Demos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mother_of_All_Demos)*", what language(s) were used to write the code for the demo?

Is any of the source code publicly available?